# Laravel 7: custom guard authentication does not work as expected

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have a multiauth project. I have the default authentication and a custom guard. At the login controller, when I make the login attempt, it authenticates as expected. However, when it gets to the homepage, the custom guard is not logged in anymore.

Users that use the custom guard already log in through an external API, so i don't want them on my users table. I just need a couple of fields to show them some content.

LoginController.php (Up to the return, attempt method returns TRUE)

```
...irrelevant code...
Auth::guard('ivao')->attempt(array('vid' => $user_array->vid, 'name' => $user_array->name, 'surname' => $user_array->surname), true);
Cookie::queue(Cookie::forever($this->cookie_name, $_COOKIE['ivao_token']));
Cookie::queue(Cookie::forever('vid', $user_array->vid));

return redirect('/');
...irrelevant code...
```

CustomProvider.php

```
class CustomUserProvider extends ServiceProvider implements UserProvider
{
    public function retrieveById($identifier)
    {

    }
    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
    {
        if(Cookie::get('rememberToken') == $token)
        {
            $user = new ApiUser();
            $user->vid = Cookie::get('vid');
            $user->name = Cookie::get('name');
            $user->surname = Cookie::get('surname');

            return $user;
        }
        else return NULL;
    }
    public function updateRememberToken(UserContract $user, $token)
    {
        if(Cookie::get('rememberToken') == $token)
        {
            Cookie::queue(Cookie::forever('vid', $user->vid));
            Cookie::queue(Cookie::forever('name', $user->name));
            Cookie::queue(Cookie::forever('surname', $user->surname));
            Cookie::queue(Cookie::forever('rememberToken'), $token);

            return TRUE;
        }
        else return FALSE;
    }
    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
        $user = new ApiUser();
        $user->vid = $credentials['vid'];
        $user->name = $credentials['name'];
        $user->surname = $credentials['surname'];

        return $user;
    }
    public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
    {
        return TRUE; //already validated at the API
    }
}
```

Homepage Controller (Here both check methods return FALSE)

```
class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index($folder= '', $page= 'inicio')
    {
        if( !(Auth::check() || Auth::guard('ivao')->check()) ) return redirect('/login');

...irrelevant code...
```

Please let me know if you need further information. Hope someone can help. I'm stuck. Thanks.

Comment: the auth system looks up the user by id and you have not defined the `retrieveById` so it won't be able to give you a user

Comment: @lagbox I thought that was called only when using loginUsingId method. Thanks for your help!